# I'm trying to install package glmnet in r running macOS Big Sur but it's not working

Tags: r, installation, gfortran, glmnet

I'm running R 4.1.0 GUI 1.76 High Sierra build (7976) on a macOS Big Sur version 11.4.
I need to install the package glmnet and I'm using the command on the console:

install.packages("glmnet")

I tried also:

install.packages("glmnet", dependencies = TRUE)

But both of them give me the same error as output:

During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C"
2: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C"
3: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C"
4: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C"

- installing *source* package 'glmnet' ...
  ** package 'glmnet' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  ** using staged installation
  ** libs
  gfortran -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c glmnet5dpclean.f -o glmnet5dpclean.o
  make: gfortran: Bad CPU type in executable
  make: *** [glmnet5dpclean.o] Error 1
  ERROR: compilation failed for package 'glmnet'
- removing '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/glmnet'

The downloaded source packages are in
'/private/var/folders/xl/dk1600ms2mj3myv7rwtkzmb40000gn/T/RtmpO7TLXK/downloaded_packages'
Warning message:
In install.packages("glmnet") :
installation of package 'glmnet' had non-zero exit status

I tried also the code:

curl -O http://mac.R-project.org/libs-arm64/pkgconfig-0.28-darwin.20-arm64.tar.gz
sudo tar fvxz pkgconfig-0.28-darwin.20-arm64.tar.gz -C /

But it didn't work.

Does anyone have an idea to help me on installing this package?

Thank you very much!
Kind regards,

Rafael

Comment: By the way, I also tried with the commands:
install.packages("devtools")
library("devtools")
install_github("cran/glmnet")

But it did not work also.